# Laravel, How to get array value in DB and use wherein?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, where-clause

I have a branch code column (in array value) in table Users.

e.g **branch_code in Table User= ["01234","03333","02030"]**

And I have a report page where user can select the branch with a select option in blade based on the user's branch code

So here is my controller

```
 $user = Auth::user();
 $user_branch = $user->branch_code;
 $region = Branch::whereIn('branch_code',[$user->branch_code])->get();
```

but i get null data, if i run `dd($user_branch)` will show

```
["01234","03333","02030"]
```

How to show the branch from array value in DB?

Answer (score 1):

So what you are getting back when doing `dd($user_branch)` is a string not an array. When doing `whereIn()`, the second parameter needs to be an array.

What you need to do is cast branch_code as an array in `User` model. Here is a link to the laravel documentation for more info:

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting

By casting it as an array you can then use it as an array in controller or view.

```
class User extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'branch_code' => 'array',
    ];
}
```